# MySQL select datetime field where date equals today

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to select a datetime field where the date equals today.  However, the query never returns any rows.

I have this row in my database:

```
id    booked_at
1     2015-08-05 09:10:56
```

The query i'm using is:

```
select date(`booked_at`) from `booking_dates` where booked_at = CURDATE();
```

Why is this not returning the row above?

Comment: E.g.: `SELECT date(booked_at) FROM booking_dates WHERE booked_at BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CURDATE(),' 23:59:59');`

Comment: @V4n1ll4 If you really care about performance you should use Strawberry's  query because its [**`Sargable`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to strip the time part of `booked_at` because `2015-08-05 09:10:56` is not equal to `2015-08-05`. Try this:

```
select date(booked_at) from booking_dates where date(booked_at) = CURDATE();
```

Comment: Yes but the date() function does this.

Comment: For select statement, but not in where clause, so use date(booked_at) = curdate()

Comment: You have to include the date function in your where condition.

Comment: The drawback with this approach is that you cannot use an index with a function acting on a column. But the advantage is that it's easy to read.

Answer (score 9):

To use index on column `booked_at`:

```
SELECT date(booked_at)
FROM booking_dates
WHERE booked_at >= CURDATE()
    AND booked_at < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```